# Why is this do/while loop crashing?

Tags: javascript

```
var doLoop = ("This is a do loop ya'll");    
var doLoopArray = [];    
var doLoopCount = 1; 

do (console.log(doLoop)); 
while(doLoopCount <= doLoop.length); {
     console.log(doLoop(0, doLoopCount));
     doLoopCount += 1;
}
```

I thought this do loop would run 23 times (number of characters in the doLoop string and then stop, but it seems to be infinite.

Comment: Your problem is that you're spelling "y'all" wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have the code body after the `while`.  That's not where it goes with a [`do-while`[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while)!  The code is supposed to go in the `do` block.

Your code is being parsed as:

```
do{
    (console.log(doLoop));
}
while(doLoopCount <= doLoop.length);
{
     console.log(doLoop(0, doLoopCount));
     doLoopCount += 1;
}
```

This is why it is an infinite loop.  It sees the code in the `{}` as a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), and not part of the `do-while` structure.

You need to structure the `do-while` correctly.  It should probably be:

```
do{
    console.log(doLoop);
    console.log(doLoop(0, doLoopCount));
    doLoopCount += 1;
} while(doLoopCount <= doLoop.length);
```

P.S. `doLoop(0, doLoopCount)` is not going to work.  `doLoop` is a string, not a function.

Comment: And what about the `do`?

Comment: What's wrong with the `do`? Surely the semi-colon belongs to the statement inside it, not the `do` itself, so should be fine.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: The `do` is actually fine.  It's like having an `if` without the `{}`.  The line (with `;`) is read as its body.

Comment: Ah I thought I could print the whole string like that, so I should use the substring method posted below?

Comment: @Jackulus: It's a string, so just do `console.log(doLoop);`, that prints the while string.  If you want part of the string, then yes you'll need to use `console.log(doLoop.substring())`.

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful, i'm just messing around on code academy, when the loop terminates it is also printing out the doLoopCount, how do I stop that?

Comment: @Jackulus: I don't know.  Sorry.

Comment: Maybe it's just a codeacademy error? In my very unlearned opinion I see no reason Why the doLoopCount should print

Answer (score 3):

`do` syntax is:

1. `do`
2. statement or block
3. `while` condition

You have your `while` condition *immediately* following the `do` and *then* you have the block.

It should be:

```
do {
    console.log(doLoop); 
    // You also need to fix this line. `doLoop` is a string, so you can't call it
    // as a function, but I'm not sure what you are trying to do here.
    console.log(doLoop(0, doLoopCount));
    doLoopCount += 1;
} while(doLoopCount <= doLoop.length);
```

Comment: What is `doLoop(0, doLoopCount)`?

Comment: I thought that was to call a certain part of the string? I'm trying to  get it to print only the 1st letter of the string, then the 1st 2 then the 1st 3.

Comment: That's the [`substring` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: thanks quentin, That whole method completely wiped itself from my brain 2 mins after learning it from codeacademy

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, with intuitive indenting.

```
var doLoop = ("This is a do loop ya'll");    
var doLoopArray = [];    
var doLoopCount = 1; 

do ({
  // You never increment doLoopCount in the body of the loop
  console.log(doLoop);
} while(doLoopCount <= doLoop.length);

// This is a separate block that is not part of the loop.
{
  // doLoop is not a function.
  console.log(doLoop(0, doLoopCount));
  doLoopCount += 1;
}
```

Your loop will run infinitely, and never reach the illegal call at the end.

What you probably meant was something like

```
var doLoopCount = 1; 
console.log(doLoop);
while (doLoopCount < doLoop.length) {
  console.log(doLoop[doLoopCount]);
  doLoopCount += 1;
}
```

or better yet

```
console.log(doLoop);
for (var doLoopCount = 0; doLoopCount < doLoop.length; ++doLoopCount) {
  console.log(doLoop[doLoopCount]);
}
```